# How to manipulate Excel with python

Tags: python, microsoft-excel

I would like to perform some operations on an existing excel files which already contains some datas and formulas. It contains also charts. The operations that I would like to do are adding some values and inserting some images. By adding those values, it should compute some datas with the formulas already contained in the file and update the charts which are already contained in the file. I would like also add some pictures at different place (worksheet) in the file.

Could you please tell me what are the best ways (libraries) to do this in Python ?

I have seen that there was a library called OpenPyxl, it seems to be really great but it seems that there is some troubles with this library to do not remove existing chart... Do you know a way to fix it ?

Thank you very much and have a nice day ! :D